# Adding a profile to an event using Facebook graph API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am successfully creating an event using the graphAPI
when i try to upload an event profile pict it just seems to hang
if i comment out basename($fileName) => '@'.$fileName it works fine.

my code looks like

```
$fb = new Facebook(array(
'appId'      => $app_id,
'secret'     => $app_secret,
'cookie'     => false,
'fileUpload' => true     
 ));            

 $fb->setAccessToken($_SESSION[ $eid.'_FB_USER_ACCESSCODE' ]);
 $data = array(  'access_token' => $_SESSION[ $eid.'_FB_USER_ACCESSCODE' ], 
             'owner'       => $_SESSION[ $eid.'_FB_USER_ACCESSCODE' ], 
             'name'        => $event->getTitle(), 
             'description' => $description,
             'start_time'  => $event->getStart(),
             'end_time'    => $event->getEnd(),
             'street'      => $event->getAddress(),
             'city'        => $event->getCity(),
             'state'       => $event->getState(),
             'zip'         => $event->getZip(),
             'latitude'    => $event->getLat(),
             'longitude'   => $event->getLong(),
             'privacy'     => 'OPEN',
             'location'    => $event->getLocation()
             ,basename($fileName) => '@'.$fileName
             ) ;        

 $result = $fb->api($_SESSION[ $eid.'_FB_USER_FBID' ]."/events","post",$data);
 $facebookEventId = $result['id'];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my problem.
The image I was trying to upload was of wrong size. I guess it was too small.

I saw a bunch of different suggestions.
One was like, about to use "picture" and another was to use basename

I got it to work by using `basename($fileName) => '@'.$fileName`, but only after uploading an image of the correct size.

Anyone know of documentation of what the sizes are that are acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the image in wrong way, it sould be:

```
"picture" => "@".realpath($fileName) //instead of basename($fileName) => '@'.$fileName
```

Ref: [Facebook Events](https://gist.github.com/1178154)

Comment: thanks for the response.
that did not make a difference. when i was using the SDK i was not getting an error message. SO i went back to using curl and the message i got was '(#324) Missing or invalid image file